# How secure is the synchronizer token pattern against cross-site forgery requests when sent over HTTP?

Tags: security, web-applications, csrf

Owasp recommends the [synchronizer token pattern](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation%3a_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern) to defend against cross-site-request-forgery. If the webpage is sent over HTTP, then a man-in-the-middle will be able to intercept the token. How much of a problem is this?

Answer (score 2):

Attacker can steal much more sensitive information like cookie with MITM, so CSRF attack won't be even necessary. If you're afraid of MITM and eavesdropping, make your webpage go through SSL. Also, make sure to don't have a single non-HTTPS request, as long as it will be enough for MITM attack like SSLStrip. You may additionally send HTTP response header "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=30000" (or your desired max-age value).

Answer (score 1):

MITM attacks on a CSRF token used over HTTP are almost never going to be a problem, unless the malicious site is on the same network as the victim (and therefore can direct the victim's traffic through itself).

What p0deje said is true, however.  If you care about a MITM stealing a CSRF token, you should definitely consider using HTTPS.